# PHP MySQL PDO INSERT then SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO tags(name) VALUES(LOWER(#[tag]));
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS ID;
```

I'm using it on MySQL using PHP PDO and i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in 
/home/cabox/workspace/backend/Toolbox.php:62 Stack trace: #0
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
$NI = (int)($DB->query(get_query("CREATE_TAG",[
    "tag" => strtolower($name)
]))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["ID"]);
```

The `get_query` functions returns a query after all `#[]` are replaced acording to the array in the second parameter. (
`get_query("CREATE_TAG",["tag" => strtolower("MyTagName")])` will return

```
INSERT INTO tags(name) VALUES(LOWER("MyTagName"));
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS ID;
```

)

Can't i insert then select in the same query?

**EDIT**:
I used this:

```
INSERT INTO tags(name) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(LOWER(#[tag]));
```

and it worked just fine.